# MS SQL - как обойтись без GROUP BY (для UPDATE TABLE)?

Tags: sql-server

Здравствуйте!

При попытке выполнить запрос база выдаёт ошибку "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'". То же самое выражение, если UPDATE... SET заменить на SELECT, отрабатывает.

Мне здесь туманно намекали, что GROUP BY чем-то нехорошо, но в гугле об этом ничего найти не могу.

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, где ошибка и чем можно заменить GROUP BY, если он действительно устарел (?). Если это важно, в полном запросе выражение лежит внутри курсора, от которого получает значения @userIDweek, @mailIDweek и @brandIDweek.

```
DECLARE @userIDweek int, @mailIDweek int, @brandIDweek int
DECLARE @cur_twoweeks CURSOR
DECLARE @Today DATETIME; 
DECLARE @TwoWeeksAgo DATETIME;
SET @Today = GETDATE();
SET @TwoWeeksAgo = DATEADD(DAY, -14, GETDATE()); 

SET @userIDweek = 46
SET @mailIDweek = 11
SET @brandIDweek = 17

UPDATE UserTableWith5suggestions
    SET saleTitle = s.title,
        saleImageUrl = s.imageUrl,
        mostViewPeriod14Days = count(sv.saleid),
        saleGuid = s.guid,
        brandID = br.id,
        brandTitle = br.title
    FROM dbo.Sales s JOIN dbo.KEY_BrandcategoryToSale b_key ON s.id = b_key.saleId 
    JOIN dbo.Brands br ON s.BrandId = br.Id 
    JOIN dbo.SaleView sv ON s.id = sv.saleId 
    JOIN dbo.SalesToMall stm ON s.id = stm.saleId 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.SaleView sv2 on sv2.id = sv.id and sv2.userId = @userIDweek
    WHERE sv.Date BETWEEN @TwoWeeksAgo 
    AND @Today 
    AND sv2.id IS NULL 
    AND s.isActive = 1
    AND stm.mallId = @mailIDweek
    AND br.id != @brandIDweek
    GROUP BY s.title, s.imageUrl, s.guid, br.title, br.id, stm.mallId,sv2.userId
    ORDER BY count(sv.saleid) desc
```

Comment: А зачем вам в update `order by` ? А по поводу `group by` вы сделайте подзапрос который данные в нужном виде возвращает и в FROM джоитене этот подзапрос, а не сами таблицы

Comment: И кстати я что то не вижу в вашем запросе условий объединения UserTableWith5suggestions с остальными таблицами ...

Comment: `Мне здесь туманно намекали, что GROUP BY чем-то нехорошо, но в гугле об этом ничего найти не могу.` Прежде чем лезть к Гуглу, неплохо бы ознакомиться с документацией. Где можно увидеть, что секции `GROUP BY` в запросе `UPDATE` вообще не предусмотрено.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Группировка в запросах UPDATE не используется потому что не вполне понятно к какому результату она должна приводить. Обновляются-то строки по одной, а не группами!

Заменить ее вы можете вложенным запросом:

```
UPDATE foo SET ...
FROM foo WHERE id in (
  SELECT ...
  FROM ...
  GROUP BY ...
)
```